# What does it mean to generate density in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

The [Angular Material source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/caad0b54ed41949f0ee529c152508749875bc9af/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss) has this property:

```
// Whether density should be generated by default.
$_mat-theme-generate-default-density: true !default;
```

What does Angular Material mean by generating density?  A simple CSS example illustrating it would be awesome.

Comment: Interesting question--I can't find it actually used anywhere, myself.

Comment: Yeah there's like a little hint in the source code:  With the recent refactoring of the theming
// system to allow for density and typography configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Material design specs. Angular Material is implementing features to config the [density of components](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/55373fbb037bdd30d95e313a6f6bb8d35bfb0276#diff-d12c63e6ecb41ab47967a3030e4f69eae6a84d183915fed67fb6968d2cabac12).

The mean of density it's about make components more easy to find, priorice actions and make it more visible. See more on [Material design density usage](https://material.io/design/layout/applying-density.html#usage)

For simple css example it could be a list of boxes and it's padding change by viewport changes.

Run the code snippet and change the window viewport size.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10vh 5vw;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">1</div>
 <div class="box">2</div>
 <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be great if there was some documentation somehow on how to actually use it, now that Material has released a beta version of the density api for the browser.  The documentation is pretty bad though, really unclear how to get it working inside a component template.